# How can you update based on the results of an IF statement in query?

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement

As the question above says, I have an IF clause in my query. Now I want to do an UPDATE based on the results of the IF clause. Any ideas how I can do this?

Here is my code:

```
string cmdstr = "UPDATE itemsordered i " +
                "INNER JOIN" +
                    "(  SELECT itemsOrdered_quantity, itemsOrdered_ID,  " +
                            "CASE WHEN itemsOrdered_quantity = '" + quantityTxtBox.Text + "' THEN 'EQUAL' " +
                                 "WHEN itemsOrdered_quantity < '" + quantityTxtBox.Text + "' THEN 'LESS' " +
                                 "WHEN itemsOrdered_quantity > '" + quantityTxtBox.Text + "' THEN 'MORE'  " +
                        "END AS r " +
                        "FROM itemsordered " +
                    ") res ON i.itemsOrdered_ID = res.itemsOrdered_ID " +
               "INNER JOIN stocksdb s ON s.stock_ID = i.stock_ID " +
               "IF (res.r = 'EQUAL') " +
               "BEGIN " +
               "SET s.stock_quantity = (s.stock_quantity + i.itemsOrdered_quantity), " +
                   "s.stock_dateUpdated = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "', " +
                   "i.itemsOrdered_status = 'RECEIVED', " +
                   "i.itemsOrdered_dateReceived = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "' " +
                   "WHERE i.itemsOrdered_ID = '" + idTxtBox.Text + "' " +
               "END " +
               "IF (res.r = 'LESS') " +
               "BEGIN " +
               "SET s.stock_quantity = (s.stock_quantity + i.itemsOrdered_quantity), " +
                   "s.stock_dateUpdated = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "', " +
                   "i.itemsOrdered_quantity = (i.itemsOrdered_quantity - " + quantityTxtBox.Text + "), " +
                   "i.itemsOrdered_dateReceived = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "' " +
                   "WHERE i.itemsOrdered_ID = '" + idTxtBox.Text + "' " +
               "END";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, db.mycon);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("ITEM RESTOCKED!");
```

It returns an error on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and says there is an error near the first`IF` clause.

Comment: Can you please provide complete error message!!!

Comment: BEGIN after If().......?

Comment: I did. It said there is an error near the first IF CLAUSE. What kind of error message are you expecting?

Comment: Should I remove the BEGIN?

Comment: Take your cmdstr and run it directly in mysql, you might have better error message.

Comment: It still returns the same error. I'll try running it in mysql

Comment: The error "... near ..." points always out a syntax error in the part **before** the quoted text in error message. After `table_references` you are not allowed to use `IF` -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html but `SET mycol = IF(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `IF ... BEGIN`, use the `CASE` expression. Remove the `BEGIN ... IF` and have only one `SET` clause. Something like:

```
SET s.stock_quantity = CASE 
                         WHEN res.r = 'EQUAL' THEN s.stock_quantity + i.itemsOrdered_quantity
                         ELSE ...
                       END,
   s.stock_dateUpdated = CASE 
                           WHEN res.r = 'EQUAL' THEN ...
                           ELSE ...
                         END,
   ....
...
```

Comment: This would work but you could also break the update into 2 separate Update queries with different WHERE clauses.  I guess it would be personal preference.

Comment: @Tom Yes, you are right. But I couldn't understand the what the OP is doing, so I suggesting this solution.

Comment: @Mahmoud - Your code is perfectly fine, I'm just saying there are 2 ways you could do it.

Comment: @John - The code would be longer with 2 queries, but would be cleaner IMHO, since with 1 query you would need a CASE statement for each field you would like to update.

Comment: Although 1 query might run faster with a very large data set.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the `IF` blocks out and have 2 different SQL statements.

Put the different `IF` criteria in the `WHERE` clause of each query.